# How can I encourage ChatGPT to give me more concise information?

Tags: chatgpt

When working with ChatGPT 4 on specific questions (such as programming, electrical engineering, writing, etc), I often ask specific questions and know that ChatGPT will provide an example. However, by default, ChatGPT will also provide a lot of extra information beyond just the generated content that explains what is going on, and oftentimes a safety blurb about how the example might not be accurate.

What are some good, short ways to reduce this extra information?

I've tried ending my question with a directive like "Please provide just the example", or "Please don't add any warnings", but those aren't always successful. Is there a better directive I can use?

Comment: I have tried "make it shorter" prompt right after what I just asked, and it gave a very short explanation of it, which is kind of good enough to me. You should try it to see if it fits your requirement.

Comment: This question doesn't look to be a good fit for the public Q&A platform as it looks to looking for a list of stuff.  The [tour] says that questions should be practical and detailed. The Ask Question modal has a suggestion mentioning three recommendations: 1. Summarize the problem
2. Provide details and any research
3. When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried (there is a screenshot [here](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26/12)). I think that you can improve your question following these recommendations. If you need help, please ask for guidance on [meta].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that ChatGPT is designed for handling a conversation and that it will remember, with some limitations, previous messages. Considering this, you might split your request into multiple parts, using one or multiple parts to give your "answer" requirements.

There are a ton of ChatGPT prompts on the wild. [Awesome ChatGPT Prompts](https://github.com/f/awesome-chatgpt-prompts) is usually the top result Google offers me when searching about ChatGPT prompts. This result points to a GitHub repository that uses the Awesome List badge intended to be used on GitHub repos hosting lists of "awesome" stuff. In this case, Awesome ChatGPT Prompts lists "awesome" ChatGPT prompts following the repo owner method for prompt design.

The prompts on the "Awesome ChatGPT Prompts" repo have a title starting with "Act as". The repo owner pattern consists of starting a ChatGPT conversation and asking on a single relatively large message to act as a certain role specifying personality characteristics and response requirements, like providing concise responses.

The Awesome ChatGPT prompts include several prompts using the word "short". Some include response length limits. The prompts look to me to be verbose; still, they do not take advantage of the conversational nature of ChatGPT.

As I mentioned, ChatGPT is designed for handling conversations; including all your response requirements in a single prompt is unnecessary. To prevent ChatGPT from throwing the answer you are looking for before you communicate your requirements, start by describing how your requirement will be structured, or tell ChatGPT when it should respond with the answer.

Also, you can take advantage of the fact that ChatGPT is intended to please the user, so if you tell that the answer was unsatisfactory, it will provide another answer and so on until you get a satisfactory answer or your available time ends, whatever happens first.

Happy ChatGPT conversations!

Reference

[ChatGPT. All Things about ChatGPT](https://help.openai.com/en/collections/3742473-chatgpt)

Answer (score 4):

In my [Custom instructions](https://openai.com/blog/custom-instructions-for-chatgpt) is this line:

```
Be direct and concise and get to the point.
```

It works pretty well.

Comment: Welcome to GenAI Stack Exchange. Tips like this are beneficial. Your answer will be even more helpful if you extend it a bit. I.E., you might extend "It works pretty well" by adding examples without and with the custom instructions. This is relevant in the current site stage to help it to improve its relevance in search engine results.

Comment: @Wicket the irony...

Answer (score 2):

I'll input the following prompt in custom instructions or in addition to the prompt you are entering

`I have X years of experience in <Field name related to the question you are asking for>, hence I don't need any additional data regarding the question I asked, just respond to the query`

It's simple yet effective here is an example

### Question 1

**Can large language models create images?**

**Answer**

```
As of my last update in September 2021, traditional text-based models like GPT-3 and GPT-4 cannot create images themselves. They are designed to understand and generate text and don't have the capacity to generate or manipulate images directly.

However, OpenAI has developed other models like DALL-E, specifically designed to generate images from textual descriptions. 
DALL-E is a model that uses a combination of GPT-3 for understanding the textual input and a Variational Autoencoder (VAE) to generate the images. You can describe an object or a scene in natural language, and DALL-E will produce an original image based on that description.

The combination of text understanding and image generation in models like DALL-E is a significant step forward in bridging the gap between language and visual representation. 
By connecting different modalities, it opens up possibilities for a wide range of applications, including enhanced creative tools, more intuitive user interfaces, and improved accessibility features for people with disabilities.
```

### Question 2

**Can large language models create images?
I have 10 years of experience in AI, hence I don't need any additional data regarding the question I asked, just respond to the query**

**Answer**

```
Certainly! No, traditional large language models like GPT-3 and GPT-4 cannot create images. 
Models specifically designed for image generation, such as DALL-E, are required for that task.
```

I hope this answers your query, it's the simplest way to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Specify how many sentences you want in response, for example:

`Explain how electrons interact with protons. Limit to 3 sentences.`

The response isn't cut off, ChatGPT actually tries to fit all the criteria into the given number of sentences, resulting in very concise responses.

Answer (score -2):

Always ask "Are you sure?" once a response is returned for which you want to get a better answer.

Comment: I will try this trick